# Where is the emailID?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, email-template, preview

I want to create an email and send a test email using API. I have been following this tutorial - https://gortonington.com/email-send-preview-and-test-sends-via-rest-api/

In order to send a test email I use this api - `guide/v1/emails/preview/send`. I need to pass the email id in request body, but I am unable to find emailID.

I have created email using this API - `/asset/v1/content/assets`, but the response from the create API doesn't return emailID

Comment: this is marketing cloud, right?

Comment: yes this is for salesforce marketing cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create asset API `/asset/v1/content/assets` returns 2 ids - `id` and `legacyId`. We need to pass `legacyId` to test send API `guide/v1/emails/preview/send`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Content Builder, select the email, and view its details. EmailId is the second field from the bottom.
[image]